# ProcessingException of response.readEntity(new GenericType<List<Domain>>() {}) for the JSON format

Tags: json, web-services, jax-rs, wildfly, resteasy

I am creating a JavaEE WebService with JSON based representation using WildFly as the application server.

for the environment I use: 
WildFly 10.0.0.Final 
Java SDK 1.8.0_101 
jboss-javaee-all-7.0-1.0.3.Final.jar, 
JAX-RS RESTEasy 3.1.4.Final

On the server side it has domain such:

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String surname;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee: " + this.firstName + " " + this.surname;
    } /* on the client side, I have similar Employee class with same toString implementation */

    /* constructor, setter and getter */
}
```

with its resource class

```
@Stateless
@Path("/employees")
public class EmployeeResource {

    @Inject
    private EmployeeManagementService service;

    @GET
    @Produces({"application/JSON", "application/XML"})
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees () {
        return service.getAllEmployees();
    }

    /* other methods */'
}
```

alongside the service and dao class which have the corresponding method to the `getAllEmployees()` resource returning `List<Employee>`.

On the client side I have a simple standalone testing class accessing the WebService

```
public class TestClient {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        String url = "http://localhost:8080/EmployeeManagement/webservice/employees"; 
        /* EmployeeManagement is the deployed war, and employees is the url-pattern specified in the web.xml */
        Response response = client.target(url)
            .request("application/json")   // .request("application/xml")
            .buildGet()
            .invoke();

        List<Employee> employees = response.readEntity(new GenericType<List<Employee>>() {});
        /* List<Employee> employees = response.readEntity(String.class); */

        for (Employee employee : employees) {
            System.out.println(employee);
        }
    }
}
```

I get `javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized Type: [null]` on the line `List<Employee> employees = response.readEntity(new GenericType<List<Employee>>() {});` receiving the data in JSON format from the WebService, but if I use the `.request("application/xml")` everything works fine and the employees are printed out as it should be.

There is no error with the returned JSON. If the `response.readEntity(new GenericType<List<Employee>>() {})` changed to `response.readEntity(String.class)` it prints the JSON in `String` just fine. The data is retrieved but seems the conversion to `List<Employee>` is on fault.

This is the error stack

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized Type: [null]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientResponse.readFrom(ClientResponse.java:300)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientResponse.readEntity(ClientResponse.java:196)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.BuiltResponse.readEntity(BuiltResponse.java:226)
    at TestClient.jsonTest3(TestClient.java:27)
    at TestClient.main(TestClient.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized Type: [null]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory._fromAny(TypeFactory.java:1189)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory.constructType(TypeFactory.java:618)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.withType(ObjectReader.java:733)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jackson.ResteasyJackson2Provider.readFrom(ResteasyJackson2Provider.java:134)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jaxb.json.JsonCollectionProvider.readFrom(JsonCollectionProvider.java:82)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.readFrom(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:66)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:56)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.security.doseta.DigitalVerificationInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(DigitalVerificationInterceptor.java:36)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:59)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientResponse.readFrom(ClientResponse.java:266)
    ... 9 more
```

So, how do I resolve this problem? 
How can I retrieve in `List<Employee>` type from JSON format?

edit:
the stacktrace with `jsonTest3` is just a method containing everything I put in this `main`. I just simplified it by putting it into `main` because there are other test methods.

Comment: http://howtodoinjava.com/jaxb/jaxb-exmaple-marshalling-and-unmarshalling-list-or-set-of-objects/  - Try Unmarshalling , insted of file ,pass the response string.`Employees emps = (Employees) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal( new StringReader(response') );`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35211495/i-am-developing-a-sample-application-using-spring-rest-api-but-i-get-an-error-w